# How can i resolve the stacktrace error, keyerror in Aws apigateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

In My project i am using AWS api gateway, Lambda function and Mongodb. I have configured lambda function using python. I have configured GET method in API Gateway. Find the below code of Lambda function.

```
db = client.userdb
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=2))
    users = db.users
    email = event['email']
    user = users.find_one({'email': email})
    return json.dumps(user, default=json_util.default)
```

when i execute lambda function,it was executed successfully. But when i configured GET method in API gateway and link with lambda function and deploy the gateway and run the API service, I will get some errors like this

```
{
"errorMessage": "'email'",
"errorType": "KeyError",
"stackTrace": [
[
  "/var/task/lambda.py",
  21,
  "lambda_handler",
  "email = event['email']"
]
```

]
}

I tried to get the details from mongodb database using email. but i am unable to get the details due to the error.How can i resolve this issue?

Comment: Please format your code properly

Comment: @yorodm I have set the code the properly,

Comment: is `email` a query variable or part of your request body? See [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/eventsources.html#eventsources-api-gateway-request) for an example of an event sent by ApiGateway to a lambda.

Comment: @yorodm I have created one collection(users) in mongodb and stored first_name,last_name,email. I tried to find the row details based on the email.